# Apollo Android error on apollo codegen install task

Tags: android, node.js, npm, graphql, apollo

> Task :app:installApolloCodegen FAILED

npm WARN deprecated apollo-codegen@0.19.1: The 'apollo-codegen' command has been replaced with the more-powerful 'apollo' CLI. Switch to 'apollo' to ensure future updates and visit https://npm.im/apollo#code-ge
neration for more information.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.17134
npm ERR! argv "C:\Users\Ghita\Documents\android life\projects\cofe-app\app\.gradle\nodejs\node-v6.7.0-win-x64\node.exe"

"C:\Users\Ghita\Documents\android life\projects\cofe-app\app\.gradle\n
odejs\node-v6.7.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"

"apollo-codegen@0.19.1" "--save" "--save-exact"
npm ERR! node v6.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! file C:\Users\Ghita\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\apollo-codegen\0.19.1\package\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! No data, empty input at 1:1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\Ghita\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\apollo-codegen\0.19.1\package\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ghita\Documents\android life\projects\cofe-app\app\build\apollo-codegen\npm-debug.log

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:installApolloCodegen'.

  > Process 'command 'C:\Users\Ghita\Documents\android life\projects\cofe-app\app.gradle\nodejs\node-v6.7.0-win-x64\node.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

**I've got this error when I try to build the project and I don't understand why package.json is empty. I have tried `npm clean cache` but with no result**

Comment: strange, I have manually deleted npm-cache from `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming`, and then I ran from android studio terminal apollo-codegen install task and it worked afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and my solution was to add this piece of code in gradle (Module:app) to download the dependencies from node

[image]

By the way, after installing **Apollo Codegen** you can delete or comment out the code block and your project will compile.

```
node {
    download = true
    version = "16.13.1"
}
```

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

For us when we are running the ant clean all we are getting this error, our FED lead suggest to run **npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/** and that resolve the issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.